# Rotating one screen with xinerama in a multihead setup

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, xinerama

I have a dual-head setup: a "main" screen at 1920X1080, and a "secondary" screen to the right of it, rotated at 90 degrees counter-clockwise. Until Friday (26.10.2012), everything was working fine, however on that day an update has caused the rotation settings in xorg.conf to be ignored.

Specifically, I had used the rotation attribute (like in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86055/rotating-screen-90-degrees-clockwise)). Also, since I have Xinerama enabled, I don't have access to xrandr and the corresponding GUI settings (due to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/157319), I think).

What should I change in my xorg.conf to have the second screen rotated again?

Here's my current `xorg.conf` (the third screen is a monitor built in into the laptop, disabled since my video card can only support 2 outputs). I haven't removed any comments to provide a possible forensic trace.

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 304.37  (buildd@allspice)  Sun Sep  9 05:59:26 UTC 2012

# commented out by update-manager, HAL is now used and auto-detects devices
# Keyboard settings are now read from /etc/default/console-setup
#Section "InputDevice"
#
#    # generated from default
#    Identifier     "Mouse0"
#    Driver         "mouse"
#    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
#    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
#    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
#    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
#EndSection
# commented out by update-manager, HAL is now used and auto-detects devices
# Keyboard settings are now read from /etc/default/console-setup
#Section "InputDevice"
#
#    # generated from default
#    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
#    Driver         "kbd"
#EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"

# commented out by update-manager, HAL is now used and auto-detects devices
# Keyboard settings are now read from /etc/default/console-setup
#    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
# commented out by update-manager, HAL is now used and auto-detects devices
# Keyboard settings are now read from /etc/default/console-setup
#    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
# Removed Option "Xinerama" "0"
# Removed Option "Xinerama" "true"
# Removed Option "Xinerama" "0"
# Removed Option "Xinerama" "1"
# Removed Option "Xinerama" "0"
# Removed Option "Xinerama" "1"
# Removed Option "Xinerama" "0"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 1920 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" LeftOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "1"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung SyncMaster"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor2"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung SMBX2235"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung SMBX2235"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 330M"
    Option         "RandRRotation" "on"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device2"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 330M"
    Option         "RandRRotation" "on"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
    Screen          2
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 330M"
    Option         "RandRRotation" "on"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "TwinView" "1"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP-0: 1366x768_60 +277+1080, DFP-1: 1920x1080 +0+0; DFP-0: 1024x768 +0+1080, DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: 1024x768i +0+1080, DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: 960x540 +0+1080, DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: 840x525 +0+1080, DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: 832x624 +0+1080, DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600 +0+1080, DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600_75 +0+1080, DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600_72 +0+1080, DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600_60 +0+1080, DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600_56 +0+1080, DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: 800x512 +0+1080, DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: 720x450 +0+1080, DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: 720x400 +0+1080, DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: 700x525 +0+1080, DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
# Removed Option "TwinView" "0"
# Removed Option "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "CRT: 1440x900 +0+0"
# Removed Option "TwinView" "1"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +277+1080, DFP-1: 1920x1080 +0+0; DFP-1: 1024x768i +0+0; DFP-1: 960x540 +0+0; DFP-1: 840x525 +0+0; DFP-1: 832x624 +0+0; DFP-1: 800x600 +0+0; DFP-1: 800x600_75 +0+0; DFP-1: 800x600_72 +0+0; DFP-1: 800x600_60 +0+0; DFP-1: 800x600_56 +0+0; DFP-1: 800x512 +0+0; DFP-1: 720x450 +0+0; DFP-1: 720x400 +0+0; DFP-1: 700x525 +0+0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1, CRT-0"
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "rotate" "cw"
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "CRT: 1680x1050 +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP-1: 1920x1080 +0+0"
    Identifier     "Screen2"
    Device         "Device2"
    Monitor        "Monitor2"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1, CRT-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-1: 1920x1080 +0+0; DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "metamodes" "CRT: 1440x900 +0+0"
# Removed Option "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP-0: 1366x768_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 1024x768 +0+0; DFP-0: 1024x768i +0+0; DFP-0: 960x540 +0+0; DFP-0: 840x525 +0+0; DFP-0: 832x624 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600_75 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600_72 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600_56 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x512 +0+0; DFP-0: 720x450 +0+0; DFP-0: 720x400 +0+0; DFP-0: 700x525 +0+0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP-1: 1920x1080 +0+0; DFP-1: 1024x768i +0+0; DFP-1: 960x540 +0+0; DFP-1: 840x525 +0+0; DFP-1: 832x624 +0+0; DFP-1: 800x600 +0+0; DFP-1: 800x600_75 +0+0; DFP-1: 800x600_72 +0+0; DFP-1: 800x600_60 +0+0; DFP-1: 800x600_56 +0+0; DFP-1: 800x512 +0+0; DFP-1: 720x450 +0+0; DFP-1: 720x400 +0+0; DFP-1: 700x525 +0+0"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1, CRT-0"
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-1: 1920x1080 +0+0; DFP-1: 800x600 +0+0; DFP-1: 800x600_75 +0+0; DFP-1: 800x600_72 +0+0; DFP-1: 800x600_60 +0+0; DFP-1: 800x600_56 +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
    Option         "Composite" "Disable"
EndSection
```

Comment: if you run through your xrandr settings in terminal what does it tell you?

Comment: Calling xrandr without arguments just says "RandR extension missing". I think this is due to the bug I linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the end, the answer was stupidly simple.

```
cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf ~/xorg.backup
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo shutdown -r now
```

And, after this, I can change the screen layout normally.

Answer (score 0):

There are two nvidia driver. One by the community and one by the nvidia folks themselves. Suggest you try both.

I think the community powered drive is called 'nv' and other is 'nvidia' ( or vice versa ). I have done the same in fedora and in some graphics cards community driver used to work better and in latest generation card the company support driver used to work well.

I have done this in Fedora before. ( i have not validated this in Ubuntu ;) )

Comment: Except by the looks of it the NVIDIA driver was not updated before the glitch started to occur. Thanks, 'though.