# Change resolution/rotation without display server

Tags: display, display-resolution, display-rotation

I have a Galaxy Book 10.6" tablet with a 1920*1280 display, but for whatever reason  Ubuntu (and every other Linux based OS) thinks it's 1280*1920. How can I change the resolution without simply rotating it in the OS (since this causes issues on other software)?

I've tried adding fb0=rotate:1 and fbcon=rotate:1 to by kernel parameters but no changes happen. I am using Intel HD 615 for the GPU.

Comment: try `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers -y && sudo apt update && sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel -y && sudo reboot` does this help?

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: ok my bad, what about this : https://www.techzim.co.zw/2017/06/tuning-intel-graphics-card-ubuntu-16-04/ it is also possible your screen is really a 1280*1920 mounted sideways to mimick a 1920*1280 and software preinstalled on windows put it the right way again.

Comment: Doesn't work either :/

Comment: what about installing xrandr `sudo apt install xrandr` and then doing :  `xrandr --newmode 1920x1080 "<generated modeline>" && xrandr --addmode VGA1 1920x1080 &&
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1920x1080` or if that doesn't work, rotating the screen with  `xrandr -o right` ?

Comment: I tried the xrandr mode stuff earlier today and it threw me a `BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)` error. `xrandr -o` is the same thing as changing rotation in ubuntu's settings, which works but breaks my programs which I mentioned in the OP

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/86055/rotating-screen-90-degrees-clockwise then perhaps the first of the two xrandr commands I suggested should work